# Post request works through Proxyman but not through Python

Tags: python, post, https, python-requests, proxyman

I need to send a post request to an API:

- when sending the request through [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) it works fine
- I tried using the same exact data (double and triple checked) to send a post request and keep getting blocked from the API (status code 401)

Now even more weird: I opened a terminal window through Proxyman, where its able to capture traffic from python libraries. And running the same script there works completely fine.

I have also [logged the trafic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdnYQ.png) and the only difference seemed to be that the terminal window through Proxyman sends a connect method first.

The data I am sending contains login details so I am unfortunately not able to include the full request, will add a snippet if that helps.

```
import requests

data = {"user": {"password": "mypassword123!", "email": "myemail@email.com"},
        "scope": "offline"}

headers = {
    "Host": "auth.site.com",
    "Accept-Language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9",
    "X-Site-Locale": "de",
    "X-Site-Device": "2OH3AB9F-2KDA-4203-B1BD-BC7D23598DD9",
    "X-Site-Device-Type": "ios",
    "X-Site-Platform-Version": "iOS 4.71.0 (6575)",
    "User-Agent": "Site - iOS(Release) - de - iPhone9,3 - iOS 15.7.7",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
}

response = requests.post(url="https://auth.site.com/v2/users/sessions", headers=headers, json=data)
```

*Please note that I have changed the URL of the API too.*

Does anyone know how I could debug my issue? What could be the problem here?